# MLE with uneasy density function

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood

I want to find the MLE of $\theta$ with the following density.

$ (1- \lvert x - \theta  \rvert)    \mathbb{1}_{[\theta-1, \theta+1]} (x)$, to confirm : $\widehat{\theta_{n}} = \overline{X_{n}}$ found by moment method.

The log likelihood would be :
$l(\theta) = \sum \ln( (1- \lvert x_{i} - \theta  \rvert)    \mathbb{1}_{[\theta-1, \theta+1]} (x) )$

But after this to derive it, it looks very difficult. How can I find the MLE, or any consistant estimation ?

Comment: Note that the likelihood is not differeniable w.r.t. $\theta$ hence that most of MLE properties will be lost. This being said the likelihood is concave w.r.t. $\theta$ so... A quick and dirty analysis can rely on $\text{d}|u| / \text{d}u = \text{sgn}(u)$ for $u \neq 0$. Please use the  `homework` tag if relevant

Comment: The MLE is almost certainly not going to be $\bar X$ for this problem... for example, if you observe $5, 6.5, 6.5, 6.5, 7$ as your data, the MLE is $\theta$ is trivially $6$.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to take into account here.

### Support dependent on $\theta$

First, you need to take into account the fact that the support of your density, say $p_\theta(x)$, depends on the parameter value; in fact, is $p_\theta(x) = 0$ for $ x \notin [\theta -1, \theta +1] $. Now, consider the case in which you have one single observation, say $x_1$. Due to the above, $\theta \notin [x_1-1, x_1 + 1 ] \implies L(\theta; x_1) = 0 $, as that value of $\theta$ could not have possibly generated $x_1$ due to that hard boundary constraint.

Now, consider the case in which you have several observations $\mathbf x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) $. Then, $\theta \notin [x_i - 1, x_i + 1] $ for any $i=1, \ldots, n$ implies $L(\theta; \mathbf x) =0$. Therefore, in order for the likelihood to be $>0$, $\theta$ has to be in the interesection $\cap_{i=1}^n [x_i - 1, x_i + 1]$, which can be seen to be $[\max_i x_i -1, \min_i x_i +1]$. Let's call that $\Theta_f$, where $f$ stands for feasible.

Notice that, depending on the values of $x_i$'s, the set $\Theta_f$ could be empty, so that asking for a ML estimator does not make sense at all; specifically, for $\Theta_f$ to be non-empty, you need $\min_i x_i +1 > \max_i x_i -1 \iff \max_i x_i - \min_i x_i <2$.

Suppose in the following that the above condition is verified so that $\Theta_f$ is non-empty.

### Non-differentiability

Now, considering only values of $\theta \in \Theta_f$, you can attempt maximizing the log-likelihood:

$$ \hat \theta_{ML} = \arg \max_{\theta \in \Theta_f} \sum \ln(1- |x_i - \theta|).$$

This function is not differentiable in each values $\theta = x_i$; let's assume $\theta$ is not one of those values and attempt differentiating it; you get:
$$ -\sum \frac{\text{sign}( \theta - x_i)}{1- |x_i - \theta|}$$
for which I cannot see at the moment an easy and general way to set it to 0, except splitting the domain $\Theta_f$ in chunks delimited by $x_i$'s for which the value of the signs are different. Moreover, even if you are able to set it to 0, and provided there is a single stationary point, you still need to make sure that the stationary point is actually a local maximum and then need to check whether the maximum is global. Specifically, you need to compute the value of the likelihood in both the local maximum as well as in all the non-differentiability points and boundaries of $\Theta_f$, and pick as $\hat \theta_{ML}$ the one which gives you the largest value.

After trying producing some plots, I expect that the stationary point will actually be the global optimum, but I cannot see a way to show it.